# Disabling Ctrl key and Alt Key in access visual basic

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

how will I disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key in my Access? in order not to perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, etc...
hoping for someone could help me in my Project.

thanks...

Comment: Why do you want it to do?

Comment: You can use key events in MS Access, but I reckon you would be better off using Update events. For example, BeforeUpdate has a cancel argument -- `Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)`

Answer (score 1):

To disable keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> using AutoKeys macro

[image]

Comment: this is in Excel? i was hoping it would be on Access

Answer (score 0):

Thanks... but i think is will be fine....

```
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    'KeyCode 83 is "S" and acCtrlMask is for Ctrl
    'Disabling Ctrl+S
    If KeyCode = 83 And Shift = acCtrlMask Then

    'Disabling Ctrl Only
    'If Shift = acCtrlMask Then
    MsgBox "Ctrl + S is disabled", vbInformation, "Kamote"
    KeyCode = 0
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()
    KeyPreview = True
    End Sub
```